# What is the difference between w[..1] and w[0] in this code, and why didn't w[0] work?

Tags: string, dictionary, rust, character, slice

```rust
  str.split_whitespace()
        .map(|w| w[..1].to_uppercase() +&w[1..].to_lowercase())
        .collect()
```

`w[0]` and `w[..1]` are exactly the same, but I know that using `w[0]` caused an error. I want to know why the error occurred.

What i know about both of them:
`w[0]` returns a single character, and `w[..1]` returns a string slice containing the first character.

Comment: Are you aware that your code panics on a string like `"ü"`?

Answer (score 1):

"`w[0]` returns a single character", no, `&str` isn't indexable by `usize` (or any integer) because indexing always [produces references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) to internals of `self` and you yourself expressed you'd expect a `char` but there just aren't any `char`s we could reference to begin with since strings are stored UTF-8 encoded in a string slice.

To avoid errors Rust doesn't provide a `Index<usize> for &str` at all but you can still explicitly tell Rust which interpretation (`u8` or `char`) you want using either of the [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes), [`bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.bytes) or [`chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) methods to get a byte slice, iterator over `u8`, iterator over `char` respectively. You can 'index' the iterators using [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth)